# Capture when recording audio, stops to receiving audio AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

There is a talking cat app well known for iOS devices, in which you speak your voice and he repeats. Analyzing this app, you'll see that it stops talking when you stop talking, that is, it stops to capture the audio when not receive another voice.

I was giving a analyzing the [methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/avfoundation/reference/AVAudioRecorderDelegate_ProtocolReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAudioRecorderDelegate/audioRecorderEndInterruption:withFlags:) of AVAudioRecorder class, and not found any method in which to capture when the User stop to talking or recorder stops to receive external audio.

How can I capture when the audio recorder stops to receiving audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process the audio stream as it is coming through. You can look at the frequency and volume of the stream. From there you can determine if the user has stopped talking.

I suggest frequency and volume as the recorder still picks up background audio. If the volume drops dramatically then the sounds the recorder is picking up must be further away from the device than before. The frequency can also lend itself to:

A.) Filter out the background audio in the audio used to replay the audio with a pitch change or any other changes. etc.
B.) I do not know the limits of frequency for the average human. But this covers the use case where the user has stopped talking, but have moved the device in such a way that the recorder still picks up load shuffling from moving fingers near the mic.

Comment: So.. in this case I will need to send my record audio stream to c/c++ project files right? Because the objetive-c not have enough commands to perform this kind of thing, am I right?

Comment: There are lower C based API's you can bridge across with Objective-C to process the stream whilst writing to a file to keep performance high

Comment: Hey man, I'm thinking here, the AVAudioRecorder have monitoring meters, and we can get the averagePowerForChannel and peakpowerforchannel, And If I create a NSTimer to get this meters in 0.5 seconds and check if the return values for avaragepower and peak power Are below than the normal average power ?

Comment: And if the average power, stay below normal for 3 seconds, we could create a command in which to stop recording, execute the audio, delete the previous audio and start recording again ?

Comment: Yes man it works very well, the metering when user don't say anything is > than 40, when user is saying anything the value is < 40, In this case I can get this values and do my idea up!